# How to initialize Go struct with anonymous member of pointer type?

Tags: go, struct, anonymous

the normal way to initial a struct with anonymous member is like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"


type AA struct {
        int
        xx string
}

func main() {
        a := &AA{
                int : 1,
                xx : "2",
        }
        fmt.Println(a) // &{1 2}
}
```

but, if the type is a pointer, can't do this any more

```
package main

import "fmt"


type AA struct {
        *int
        xx string
}

func main() {
        i := 1
        a := &AA{
                *int : &i,
                xx : "2",
        }
        fmt.Println(a)
}
// .\hello.go:14: invalid field name *int in struct initializer
```

is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

The name of `*int` field is just `int`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type AA struct {
    *int
    xx string
}

func main() {
    i := 1
    a := &AA{
        int: &i,
        xx:  "2",
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: Specced [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types). Packages also don't become part of the field's name. Note that if you embed a lowercase typename like `int` it will wind up an unexported field, i.e., you won't be able to do `a.int` from another package.